# Pattern matching any 2-tuple

Tags: haskell

I want a function deciding if the passed argument is a 2-tuple, but the following does not compile.

```
is2Tuple :: a -> Bool
is2Tuple (_, _) = True
is2Tuple _      = False
```

It gives the following error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘(a0, b0)’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          isPair :: forall a. a -> Bool
        at helloworld.hs:30:1-19
    • In the pattern: (_, _)
      In an equation for ‘isPair’: isPair (_, _) = True
    • Relevant bindings include
        isPair :: a -> Bool (bound at helloworld.hs:31:1)
   |
2  | isPair (_, _) = True
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: A function as the one defined here makes no sense, since you can only use patterns that use data constructors of the type in the signature. `(_, _)` is not a data constructor of `a`. Haskell is a statically typed language. After the compilation phase, all the types are known. It therfore makes not much sense to have a function `is2Tuple` in the first place.

Comment: Is it possible to make a version where ‘a’ is a type variable?

Comment: You can not check types at runtime, that would horribly break parametricity. At best, you can if you change the type to `isPair :: Typeable a => a  ->Bool` so that type information is retained at runtime, but still, that sounds as a quite bad idea in most common contexts. Don't follow this path carelessly without being sure of what you are trying to achieve. Why do you _need_ to check that? This might be an XY problem.

Comment: I have a type variable ‘a’ and it could be one type in production and another type in testing. And depending on which type it is, different results are returned. What’s the best way to handle this?

Comment: `is2Tuple :: (a,b) -> Bool; is2Tuple _ = True`.  (joke)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comments, what you're really looking for is a way to define a function that works with several parameter types, and has separate implementations for each type. Quote: "*one type in production and another type in testing*". This is usually called "*overloading*".

The way to overload functions is Haskell is *type classes*. They are somewhat like interfaces in Java or C#, except you get to define them separately from the types, and the compiler picks the one you need automatically.

If you want your function to work with two different types, and have different implementations for those types, make this function a member of a type class:

```
class MyClass a where
    f :: a -> String
```

And then provide two instances of this class for the two types:

```
instance MyClass (a, b) where
    f (a, b) = "It's a tuple"

instance MyClass Int where
    f a = "It's an Int"
```

Then the compiler will be able to pick the right implementation based on paramater types at call sites:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (f ("foo", "bar"))  -- prints "It's a tuple"
    print (f (42 :: Int))     -- prints "It's an Int"
```

It you try to use the function with a type for which there is no implementation, the compiler will catch you:

```
    print (f True)  -- ERROR: no instance MyClass Bool
```